# Create time operation that controls memory and CPU consumption ios

Tags: ios, iphone, instruments

Good evening.

My target is to create an application that runs in the background and consumes a controllable amount of recources. CPU, Memory, network resources, etc.

The user will set the time the operation will run for, the CPU consumption level, and the memory occupied by the app.

When he presses "start" the app will create the operation with a timer for a specific amount of time and will start a task that consumes the resources specified...

I am not really sure how to use controllable resources. Can someone, please point me to the right direction?

Regards,

LSonic

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to consume these resources while the app is in the background, foreground, or both?

Comment: both maybe have a control for that as well... In terms of memory, I will load text (massive amounts of text) but for CPU, I'm not really sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your app is in the background, you no longer have control of your resources. There are a few things that can be done to have *some* resources, but if your app attempts to hog or deliberately consume resources, you will be terminated.

While your app is in the foreground, you can use as much memory and CPU time as you want, but at your own hazard. If you stall the UI thread too long, you will be killed. If the system believes your background thread is hung at 100% CPU usage, you will also be killed.

Why are you trying to do this? If we knew your goals, we may be able to offer better ways to achieve them. What you are suggesting now is a dead end.

Comment: Main target is to create a CPU/Memory stress test where I will control the variables. Put that app on the background to perform the actions indicated and then run my actual app to see how it performs under a stressed environment like that.

Comment: The closest thing you can achieve to background stress testing is to create an app that plays music. The music can be silence, but that will give your app a chance to use memory and CPU time in the background while another app is active. You'll have to do the leg work from here and post another question when you get stuck.

Comment: created an app that searches for primes from 100 up to 1.000.000. quite intensive. then used [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    }]; to run it in the background... works quite well...